# Can you make SQL Server datetimeoffset "nullable"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetimeoffset

I have an API that receives datetimeoffsets, and stored in a SQL Server in a `DateTimeOffset` column. However, some of the users of the API do not have the timezone information.

In that case, the system treat this like it is UTC.

I there any clever way to fool the SQL Server into having the timezone information optional/nullable?

In that case I could transform it to localtime if there was timezone information, or just show the datetime unmodified if no timezone information was present.

Comment: You can store such dates in a "normal" datetime column.

Comment: Good question. I'm afraid, there is no such option and you'll need to use an additional `timezoneInformationIsAccurate` bit field.

Comment: Maybe just use `UTC`

Comment: I'm having a hard time reconciling your two statements of "the system treat this like it is UTC" (from the question) and "we can not make any assumptions" (from a comment to an answer below). That is, aren't you implicitly making an assumption in the case where the user is (for whatever reason) unable to provide TZ info?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot *remove* the offset from `datetimeoffset` datatype. Some workarounds:

- Use `datetimeoffset` and `datetime2` columns and populate one or the other depending on whether the input contains timezone information or not.
- Use `datetime2` to store the datetime part of the input and `varchar(6)` to store the timezone offset, if present.
- Use [`at time zone`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to convert the input to a specific timezone and store the result as `datetimeoffset`. Here is an example:

```
select cast('2022-01-01 12:00:00 -05:00' as datetimeoffset);                          -- 2022-01-01 12:00:00 -05:00
select cast('2022-06-01 12:00:00 -04:00' as datetimeoffset);                          -- 2022-06-01 12:00:00 -04:00
select cast('2022-01-01 12:00:00' as datetime2) at time zone 'Eastern Standard Time'; -- 2022-01-01 12:00:00 -05:00
select cast('2022-06-01 12:00:00' as datetime2) at time zone 'Eastern Standard Time'; -- 2022-06-01 12:00:00 -04:00
```

Comment: Yes, we do assume that it is localtime.
But we don't know the name of the local timezone, some users simply cannot supply timezone information, and this is a shipping company so we can not make any assumptions besides , if no zone information is provided, it must be localtime, -wherever local then is...

Comment: But you know where the SQL Server is running and what timezone it is using, right?

Comment: Yes, but I cannot see how that is going to help me?
The datetime we receives is arrivaltimes all over the globe.

Comment: I've shown you how to convert timezone-less dates to dates with timezone.

Comment: I still don't get it?
For example, I get information that a shipment from India arrives New York 9:22 and no timezone information is given. 
The sql server is located in Paris.

If I just saves the 9:22 without timezone in the database, it treats that as 9:22 UTC, and when that value is then shown in the GUI, it is 4 hours off what you would expect.

I cannot see how the timezone where the sqlserver becomes relevant?

But, if could store the timezone information as "NULL" in the database, I would know that this row, would be without timezone, and the value would just be shown.

Comment: I see the problem now. One solution is to specify the destination timezone (e.g. Eastern Time Zone for New York) in the `AT TIME ZONE`. This would not be practical as you'll need to store timezone name in the destinations table (if you have one). Or use another `datetime2` column and populate one or the other depending on whether the api date contains timezone information or not.

Answer (score 0):

The conclusion is: No, it is not possible.

You have to find another way to solve the problem.